# Broken CSS stackoverflow

Tags: bug, design

I know this is not a big issue but could be fixed:

[image]

I guess it was not expected a user to  get 100 000 points about given tag. The screenshot is made from this profile - https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: Should we add a bug-caused-by-jon-skeet tag?

Comment: @hello he's definitely an edge case, but it seems to be a large edge.

Comment: fixing this would only defer the problem... since he'll eventually have > 999Y rep in that tag

Comment: @m0sa At that point you can just change it to 1m rather than 1000k.

Comment: [Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotta-)

Comment: Nothing but trouble that Skeet guy!

Comment: People are always raising green flags for questions which are in relation with jon skeet. See, if this is a bug then what would you people tell, after seeing the flair of mine. A character is cutting of from my name.